# didSelectItemAtIndexPath: sometimes not called

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a strange behaviour of my `UICollectionView`. Sometimes `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` not called. But if I select another item and them I'm available to click previous item.

1. Delegates are ok.
2. Gesture recognizers are disabled
3. `UICollectionView` is in front. Nothing before this

My Code:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (self.activeCollectionViewObjects.count > section) {
            NSArray *array = self.activeCollectionViewObjects[section];
            return array.count;
        }
    }
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    VenueLayoutCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kVenueLayoutCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.activeCollectionViewCellsDictionary[indexPath] = cell;
    if (self.activeCollectionViewObjects.count > indexPath.section) {
        NSArray *rows = self.activeCollectionViewObjects[indexPath.section];
        if (rows.count > indexPath.row) {
            if ([rows[indexPath.row] isKindOfClass:[VenueLayoutCellObject class]]) {
                VenueLayoutCellObject *object = rows[indexPath.row];
                cell.cellObject = object;

            }
        }
    }
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSLog(@"hello");
}
```

Where could I be wrong? Thanks in advance

Gesture Recognizers are disabled now. I've set the breakpoint and they doesn't hire

Comment: It's impossible to tell without any real code...

Comment: Please post the answer if you solved it

Answer (score 2):

make sure to call the proper CollectionView delegate

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView     didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

You may be calling

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. As I said - delegates are ok :) And It called correct and only at a random moment it doesn't work :(

Comment: @ArtemZ. have you implemented some kind of single tap gestures in your class?

Comment: yes I did, but they are disabled. I've set the breakpoint - they are not called.